# Severe errors in solr configuration in Cygwin

Tags: solr

I am trying to install solr on Tomcat 7.0.27 on my 64 bit Windows 7 professional using Cygwin.

I copied solr.war file from cygwin/apache-solr-3.4.0 into Tomcat under Tomcat/WebApps.

When I do this, it shows Solr admin on localhost:8080/solr

But configuration problem occurs when I update web.xml file (changing from /put/your/solr/home/here   to C:\cygwin\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr

I can no longer even see solr admin on localhost:8080/solr

I would appreciate if you can help me (I am new to Solr and programming overall)

Comment: Any error within the solr log file? Have a look at your `catalina.out`. What do you change exactly within your `web.xml`?

Comment: Please elaborate or add your logs when you say "But configuration problem occurs when I update web.xml file "

Comment: Javanna, I changed /put/your/solr/home/here to C:\cygwin\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr

Answer (score 0):

Try C:/cygwin/apache-solr-3.4.0/example/solr